# React native open external link on notification using Notifee

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, custom-activity

How can I open an external link by pressing the push notification **without opening the app**?

I want to use [FCM](https://rnfirebase.io/) and [Notifee](https://notifee.app/) for this purpose.